# Crash when tapping clear on Fire Tv which has an Outlined Text Field on jetpack compose but it works perfectly fine on Android Tv

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, amazon-fire-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.abc.firetv.screen.debug, PID: 3070
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while applying EditCommand batch to
> buffer (length=1, composition=null, selection=TextRange(1, 1)):
> CommitTextCommand(text.length=0, newCursorPosition=0)
> > DeleteSurroundingTextCommand(lengthBeforeCursor=2147483647, lengthAfterCursor=2147483647)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditProcessor.apply(EditProcessor.kt:117)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion.onEditCommand$foundation_release(TextFieldDelegate.kt:194)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:254)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:251)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid$createInputConnection$1.onEditCommands(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:128)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.endBatchEditInternal(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:157)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.endBatchEdit(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:151)
> at
> com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:486)
> at
> com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6200)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:801)
> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: end cannot be negative.
> [start: 1, end: -2147483648]
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.packWithCheck(TextRange.kt:124)
> at androidx.compose.ui.text.TextRangeKt.TextRange(TextRange.kt:37)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditingBuffer.delete$ui_text_release(EditingBuffer.kt:211)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.DeleteSurroundingTextCommand.applyTo(EditCommand.kt:266)
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.EditProcessor.apply(EditProcessor.kt:114)
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion.onEditCommand$foundation_release(TextFieldDelegate.kt:194) 
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:254) 
> at
> androidx.compose.foundation.text.TextFieldDelegate$Companion$restartInput$1.invoke(TextFieldDelegate.kt:251) 
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.TextInputServiceAndroid$createInputConnection$1.onEditCommands(TextInputServiceAndroid.android.kt:128) 
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.endBatchEditInternal(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:157) 
> at
> androidx.compose.ui.text.input.RecordingInputConnection.endBatchEdit(RecordingInputConnection.android.kt:151) 
> at
> com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:486) 
> at
> com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:93) 
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6200) 
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
> at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:911) 
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:801) 
> 2023-03-24 23:48:45.317  3070-3070  Process
> com.abc.firetv.screen.debug         I  Sending signal. PID: 3070 SIG:
> 9 2023-03-24 23:48:45.428   613-656   InputDispatcher         pid-613
> E  channel 'a814ebc
> com.abc.firetv.screen.debug/tv.abc.mobile.presentation.onboarding.dispatch.controller.DispatchActivity
> (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!

This crash is occuring when I am pressing clear on the soft keyboard and works fine on Android Tv but crashes on fire t.Also, for the crash to happen, we must have typed something.

Comment: Looks like this issue addressed in this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/256543967#comment4). Please verify on `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.0-alpha01` version if this is still happening.

Comment: yes... tested it.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

As [vighnesh153 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75840100/crash-when-tapping-clear-on-fire-tv-which-has-an-outlined-text-field-on-jetpack#comment134097660_75840100), the [issue is tracked in a bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/256543967#comment4) and was addressed in `androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.0-alpha01`.